# How to get a system tray icon for Teams when started as a Chromium app?

Tags: chromium, i3, teams

I am running i3 as a window manager together with Polybar. I need to run Teams for work, but have some issues with the Teams application when running Arch in a VM. Regardless, I would like to run Teams by just starting it as a Chromium application as follows:

```
chromium --app=https://teams.microsoft.com
```

This works great. Notifications are delivered through dunst, no mic auto adjust with a Chromium extension. The only thing I am missing now is a way to show a tray icon that shows me any incoming pending messages. Chromium supposedly will show a system tray icon but I do not see it (the system tray itself works fine); I have 'continue to run in background' enabled in Chromium.

Is it somehow possible to let Chromium show a Teams systray icon with some status as the app does?

Comment: Try to use a [Progressive Web App](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps-chromium/). Use Chrome or Edge if Chromium can't do it. See [article1](https://dev.to/andrioid/adding-progressive-web-apps-pwa-to-the-linux-desktop-ik) or [article2](https://www.ampercent.com/install-progressive-web-apps/28167/).

Comment: @harrymc, interesting, never heard of Progressive Web Apps. Chrome is a no for me, but I'll check support with Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

No. All `chromium --app` does is open the web page in chromium. All the page knows is that it is opened in a web browser, and websites can't create systray icons.